# Change color of <tr> when element inside is in focus

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of tr element when user select a text box inside it. The focus pseudo-class is not working with it. <del>Can this be achieved without JavaScript ?</del>

html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
tr:focus
{
    background:yellow;
}​
```

**Update1:**
Looks like there is no CSS only method. What is the easiest way to do this using JavaScript ?

Comment: It would be nice if you use this on input:focus this will work

Comment: Yes, focus gives nice effect with input but I wan't to highlight whole row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. There's no subject selector in CSS3, there will be one in [CSS4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject) though.

**EDIT**:

A pure JavaScript solution could be

```
var i;
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("tr > td > input");
for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i){
    inputs[i].addEventListener('focus',function(e){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.className += ' highlight';        
    });
    inputs[i].addEventListener('blur',function(e){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.className.replace(/\s*highlight\s*/ig,' ');
    });
}
```

However, this won't work in IE≤7, as versons prior 8 don't know [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) ([demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EH8Q3/)). If you want a care-free cross-browser solution you could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the following code ([demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EH8Q3/1/)):

```
$("tr > td > input").focus(function(e){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('highlight');
}).blur(function(e){
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Don't forget to add a class `tr.highlight` to your CSS. Keep in mind that jQuery will drop support of old browsers in future releases (see [Browser Support](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)), so you'll have to use jQuery 1.x for IE ≤8.

Answer (score 12):

What about using :focus-within...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
tr:focus-within {
  background:yellow;
  }​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuha0t4g/)

[What helped me.](https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/05/14/focus-within.html) As the chosen answer did not work for me.

Comment: @Aamir Rizwan This should be the selected answer for the CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible to make a `tr` element focusable, on sufficiently new browsers, by using a `tabindex` attribute on it, e.g. `<tr tabindex="1">`.

However, the method of focusing is browser-dependent, and focusable table rows can be a usability nightmare. For example, both on IE and on Firefox, the row is focused on when the TAB key is used suitably, but a focused row does not take input. The use would need to hit TAB again to get to the input field. On Firefox, but not on IE, the row can also be focused on by clicking, though not by clicking on the input field (since that would focus on that field). If you use `label` markup, as recommendable for usability and accessibility, e.g.

```
<table>
<tr tabindex="1">
    <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

… then clicking on the label focuses on the input field (one of the reasons for using `label` markup!), not on the row element.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't without JavaScript.

Comment: It's possible, there's an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54259425/409102

Comment: Well, focus-within wasn't around in 2012 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Was just about to say that: http://jsfiddle.net/qHmGe/

Comment: Include the solution in the answer's text, not in external links. Or, duplicate essential content of external links, for preservation purposes.