# Add glow to a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there anyway to add a glow around one row in a table? Similar to this form.

[image]

Heres the code to make this happen, from [CSS/HTML: Create a glowing border around an Input Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670879/css-html-create-a-glowing-border-around-an-input-field)

```
.glowing-border {
    border: 2px solid #dadada;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.glowing-border:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

Anyone know how I could transfer this style to a table row?

Comment: What html are you working with? Multiple cells per row, or just one? What are the contents that this 'glow' should around, or in? *Show* us what *you* want, what you're working on.

Answer (score 2):

Not really what you are after, but you can apply your css to the td element:

```
td {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/bbMS5/1/

Comment: That style can apply to `tr`s too, or to a class that can be applied to `tr`s: see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/H2USP/). So it's easy to make all rows glow, or just a row or a cell with a certain class.

Comment: @Rory O'Kane that doesn't work on my browser and I'm using chrome 28.0.1472.0 canary

Answer (score 0):

in css it is not done on **tr**

it is already discuss [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160445/change-color-of-tr-when-element-inside-is-in-focus)

see also [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) to attractive tr in tables

Comment: so there would be no way to add the border with jQuery?

Comment: @Daft you should have checked the link though this post doesn't answer your question.

Comment: yes by $("#your selector").css('border','1px solid gray');  // see http://api.jquery.com/css/